# set character/symbol from a particular font instead of bullet in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, symbols, lists, itemize

I am using fontspec and beamer and would like to change the bullet symbol of "itemize" to a given character.

I have tried

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[]
```

Before and after `\begin{document}`, but it did not work.

So far, the only thing that works is `\item[☙]`, but it's too cumbersome to use every time I want an item.

A MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[☙]
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \item \item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not a MWE. First, I very much doubt it is Minimal. (If it is, why not just use unshadowed blocks or maybe lining numbers or unnumbered captions? In saying this is a MWE, you are saying that all of those things must be included to demonstrate the problem.) Second, it definitely isn't Working as it will not compile being only a fragment. Third, it is not an Example because it doesn't demonstrate the problem. I'd suggest editing it to be a real MWE so people can help you more effectively. Make sure, too, that you use only fonts everyone has unless they are needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @cfr. I have changed the MWE. It's working effortlessly now.

Answer (score 5):

The `[☙]` option is not predefined, so it has no effect; the syntax should be like

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
```

where `circle` has been defined with `\defbeamertemplate`. Here's a complete example

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{fleuron}{☙}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[fleuron]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary "define" a style, though it's the best solution. You also can write

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{☙}
```

(with braces, not square brackets).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Works perfectly. Why would defining a style be a "better" solution? Can you please make a more complete answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If you define a style you can change between styles: you can use the default style for one list and your own style for another.